# seaborn.objects common labels is not working instead it gives separate label to each plots

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

Hi I am trying to give title to this plot. Instead of having a common label, the labels are shared among the plots. Is there any way to not switching from seaborn object. [image: this is the plot]

```
(
    so.Plot(df,x="sepal_length",y="sepal_width")
    .add(so.Dot(alpha = .5,pointsize=1),col = None)
    .add(so.Dot(alpha=.5,pointsize=3,color='darkblue'),legend=False)
    .add(so.Line(color="r"),so.PolyFit(1))
    .facet("species",wrap=2)
    .share(x=True,y=True)
    .label(title="Scatter Plot between Sepal \nLength and Sepal Width")
)
```

I tried .share(label=True) but it does not work.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: @mwaskom I've encountered a similar use-case - what is desired is something like `matplotlib`'s `suptitle` method that adds a single overarching title to a figure of subplots. What is happening here is that `so` is duplicating the title for each and every subplot. I think what's needed is a way to inform `so` that a title should be for the entire plot, rather than for individual subplots.